# Microsoft Teams API Create Meetings Extension Live Video Frame Capture

Tags: javascript, jsx, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I want to build an application about image processing with MS Teams Meetings. So how can i get frames on live stream? Can I get video frames or video stream data ? Is there any possible way to do this ?

Thanks.

I tried to use Microsoft Teams JS library. But I can't find any resources about getting video frames or video stream during video call.

Comment: Same issue is being tracked here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/image-proccessing-on-ms-teams/m-p/3815113#M7693. Please follow this thread for further updates. Thank you.